# Is it possible to build an iOS framework that delivers all but the UI?

Tags: ios, frameworks, target

Summary: I want to build three apps that are technically the same, but have a totally different design.

---

I would like to build iOS applications that has a custom interface, a CoreData model and some custom appearance (UITableViewCell / UIView).

Because I need to build three similar apps, I would like to build a framework that includes the model and some controlling behavior that I can reuse in all of them. If a bug is found I only need to fix it in the framework and recompile each app.

The user interaction and the view sequence are all the same, but the design of the three apps should be individual (e.g. different UITableViewCells with different heights, arrangements of buttons, ...).

Different targets are not an option, because I don't want to just exchange some background images but real individual layouts. Also, different targets would require many many if/else if/... blocks and that makes code look ugly and gets out of control if I create the fourth target.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: For iOS, look at a static library instead of a framework but otherwise what you're suggesting makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a terribly helpful suggestion, but we do this where I work using Titanium Studios and the Alloy MVC framework. Tho, I assume you want to write full native iOS code, not Titanium JS.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're looking for is similar to [Model-View-ViewModel](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), and is becoming increasingly popular among desktop developers.  You create a backend framework that is either cross-platform, or has the necessaries to be such, that encapsulates only logic, then design an application around that framework.  And if you're not into targets, the next logical steps would be separate projects.